# How to send email more than one "To Reciepents" using outlook rest api v1.0

Tags: rest, laravel-5, outlook, outlook-restapi

I am working with outlook rest api v1.0 in laravel 5.4 using microsoft graph package. Just need to know that how i can send email more than one receipent using outlook create message api which is (api/v1.0/me/sendemail).

Also let me know is there any package available in php/laravel for v2.0 .

using this snippet.

```
$subject = "any thing "; $to = "demo@email.com", $content = "Hi this is demo"; 

{ "Message":
 { "Subject": $subject,
 "Body": { "ContentType": "Text", "Content": $content },

 "ToRecipients": [ { "EmailAddress": { "Address": $to, } } ], 

"Attachments": [ {
 "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
 "Name": "menu.txt", "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk=" } ] }, 
 "SaveToSentItems": "false" 

}
```

Comment: Where is your code for send email to one user?

Comment: the simple code which is using  here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages

Comment: $subject = "any thing "; $to = "demo@email.com", $content =  "Hi this is demo";
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": $subject,
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": $content
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": $to,
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}

More explained form .

Comment: add this in your question

Comment: @DsRaj please check the question.

Comment: try something Like this: demo@email.com,demo3@email.com

Comment: "ToRecipients": [ { "EmailAddress": { "Address": "demo@email.com,demo3@email.com", } } ]
Like this ?

Comment: $to = "demo@email.com,demo2@gmail.com" and 
$to = ["demo@email.com","demo2@email.com"]
Try both one by one

Comment: @DsRaj alright.

Comment: Have you check ?

Comment: Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/example@outlook.com/sendmail` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"error": {
"code": "RequestBodyRead",
"message": "An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading (truncated...)

When using with  $to = ["demo@email.com","demo2@email.com"]

Comment: Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/expample@outlook.com/sendmail` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"error": {
"code": "ErrorInvalidRecipients",
"message": "At least one recipient isn't valid., Recipient \ (truncated...)

when usign this $to = "demo@email.com,demo2@gmail.com"

Comment: Hi, @DsRaj 
I found a way around.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => Array
                (
                    [Address] => demo1@example.com
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => Array
                (
                    [Address] => demo2@example.com
                )

        )

)

Comment: $emails =  'demo1@example.com,demo2@example.com';
$to =  explode(',',$emails);


if(count($to) > 1 ){
    
foreach($to as  $t){
   $a[] = array('EmailAddress'=>array('Address'=>$t));
    }
    
}else{  
$a[] = array('EmailAddress'=>array('Address'=>$emails));
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: It means if you pass this in array then it is working right?

Comment: yes... i tried it hard coded like this.

"ToRecipients"=>array(
        array(
            "EmailAddress"=>array(
                "Address"=>"example.15@hotmail.com",
               
              )
          ),
        array(
            "EmailAddress"=>array(
               
                "Address"=>"example.14@hotmail.com",
              )
          ),
        ),

so it worked.

Comment: Finally worked :)

Comment: yes. and thanks for your interest.

Comment: Add this as an answer so it will help for other users.

Comment: @DsRaj Yeah sure.

Comment: @DsRaj please check the answer and share your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that , for sending email on multiple address you need  this format

```
"ToRecipient" => array(
    array(
        "EmailAddress"=>array(
            "Address"=>'first_email@emailcom',

          )
      ),
    array(
        "EmailAddress"=>array(

            "Address"=>"second_email@email.com",
          )
      ),
    ),
```

So we need to make this format dynamically like this

```
$emails = 'first_email@email.com,second_email@email.com'; 
  $to = explode(',',$emails); 
    if(count($to) > 1 )
     { 

       foreach($to as $t){ 
        $a[] = array('EmailAddress'=>array('Address'=>$t)); 
        } 

     }else

     { 
       $a[] = array('EmailAddress'=>array('Address'=>$emails)); 
     }
```

Then simple pass the $a in "ToRecipient" object like this

```
"ToRecipient"=>$a
```

Done.